# Intercept touches with an overlay in UIImagePicker?

Tags: xcode

I'm working on an iPhone app which uses the camera. I want to be able to intercept touches on the camera with a subview however when you touch the subview it still thinks I'm touching the camera. Is there anyway of intercepting the touch events? I've noticed that buttons still work on the subview just not the touch events. 
If anyone could help it would be much appreciated. 
Thanks!